# Given that readFileSync only reads the contents of a file, how do you read an entire file as bytes or hex characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

The documentation for [Node.js FS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) says that NodeJS' `readFileSync` only returns the contents of the target file. That link is to documentation for `readFile` but the section on `readFileSync` says to refer to `readFile`s docs. Allegedly, NodeJS `readFile` **"asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file."**

I want to generate a hash of a file. I use the `crypto` library but am willing to use other libraries or methods. The hash cannot be based on just the contents of the file. It has to use all the bytes of the file itself. For example, assume the path targeted a file that uses Microsoft's PE format. The bytes in the file header that represent the `Machine`, `NumberOfSections`, and etc. should be used in the hash. I want to do that to a text file. Also, this is a link to a Microsoft article on the PE Format: [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format). So few bytes are printed to console by the code below, implying that only the contents are read.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

function hash (path) {
    const hash_object = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    const file_as_buffer = fs.readFileSync(path)
    hash_object.update(file_as_buffer);
    const hash_string = hash_object.digest('hex');
    
    console.log("Has input", file_as_buffer);

    return hash_string;
}
hash('test.txt');
```

Assuming the file only contains a newline character, the output in the console for this is a single byte. How do I use the bytes that represent the entire text file - including metadata like author and creation date - as input for the hash function?

I confirmed that on identical copies of the file, using the code above returns the same hash for different copies of the same file. This happens even if their file name is different or they were created a few minutes apart. How do I avoid that?

Comment: "Contents of the file" and "bytes of the file are the same thing" so it's entirely unclear what you're asking for help with.  With the arguments you are using to `fs.readFileSync(path)`, it returns a `Buffer` object that contains the exact bytes of the entire file.  You have the data right there.

Comment: Note: This is apparently not your real code because your function `hash` is not declared with proper syntax.  It should be `function hash() {  }`.  Note the `()` that you are missing.

Comment: A newline character can indeed be a single byte.  On some platforms a newline is designated by just a single `0xA` byte (a linefeed character).

Comment: To see exactly what you have in your file, add a `console.log(file_as_buffer)`.  That should show you the exact contents of the buffer which will be your entire file contents shown as binary.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am looking to hash the entire file including the bytes for metadata. This is not the actual code. There are other methods for opening a directory, listing files, and etc. I will commit those anyway since they are working as intended.

Comment: Well, `fs.readFileSync()` is reading the entire binary file - every byte that is in the file.  I'm not sure what you mean by metadata?  It sounds like you think `fs.readFileSync()` is skipping some header of the file or something like that.  That is NOT what it does.  It just dumps the entire bits of the file in a buffer and returns that to you.  There is no interpretation of the file at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 The bytes do match exactly when I log `file_as_buffer` to console. Still, I want the bytes that represent the metadata to be included in the hash. If someone changed the file name or replaced it with an exact copy, I want the hash to be different. The SHA 256 algorithm seems to give me different results from exact content copies, but it might just be because of the algorithm itself and not the input. I use the crypto library.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just confirmed that on identical copies of the file, even using `crypto` and the SHA 256 algorithm returns the same hash for different copies of the same file. If the file contents are the same and NO RANDOM SALT is provided like in my function above, the resulting hash is the same.

Comment: Then, you have to add whatever metadata you want to include into the hash.  I don't know what you want to include: filename, createTime, modifyTime?  That info comes from something like `fs.stat()` and you can get it separately and add it into your hash.  You will probably want some delimiter from the file data so the file data and metadata are a bit separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final answer I used. It is nearly the same as Charlie's [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69893223/11048997) I just accepted the suggestions in the comments to select specific items from the results of `fs.statSync`.  I took the sum of `mtime` (time modified, I assume), `ctime` (time created), and `size`. The next operations are all done in one line. I explicitly converted the sum into a string and created a buffer from the string. Last, I concatenated the two buffers.

```
function hash(path: string): string {
    const hash_object = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    const file_as_buffer = fs.readFileSync(path)

    let blockfile_stat = fs.statSync(path);
    let blockfile_stat_num: number = blockfile_stat.mtimeMs +
        blockfile_stat.ctimeMs + blockfile_stat.size;

    hash_object.update(Buffer.concat(
        [file_as_buffer, Buffer.from(String(blockfile_stat_num))])
    );
    const hash_string = hash_object.digest('hex');

    return hash_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the hash to be different for different files with the same contents, you will have to consider the file metadata which you can get from `fs.stat`.

```
function hash (path) {
    const hash_object = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    const file_as_buffer = fs.readFileSync(path);

    const file_meta = fs.statSync(path);                           // Get file stats    
    const allFile = Buffer.concat([file_as_buffer, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(file_meta))]);    //Add them to the input buffer for hashing

    hash_object.update(allFile);
    const hash_string = hash_object.digest('hex');
    
    console.log("Has input", file_as_buffer);

    return hash_string;
}
```

Comment: I got an error passing in `file_meta` for `Buffer.concat`. I use TypeScript so I changed it to `Buffer.concat([file_as_buffer, Buffer.from(String(file_meta))])`. Will that break anything?

Comment: When I print `file_meta` to console it's just [Object object]. I could grab certain members from `file_meta` and add them to the hash input.

Comment: The `fs.stat` gives out a js object. I just edited the answer to convert it to a buffer.

Comment: @JoachimRives - I would not suggest using the entire `fs.stat()` object in your  hash.  Pick, out the items you actually care about and put them in your own object.

Comment: I too accept that suggestion. You can always filter out unnecessary fields from the stat object.